# Linear independence as a way to gauge predictor usefulness.

Tags: linear-regression, linear-independence

**Background.**

The multiple linear regression model is of the form

$$
Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \cdots + \beta_nX_n + \epsilon
$$

where we assume $\epsilon$ is normally distributed with constant variance. One way to decide whether any of the predictors are useful in predicting the response $Y$ is to test the following null hypothesis against the alternative:

$$
H_0: \beta_1 = \cdots = \beta_n =0
$$

versus

$$
H_1: \beta_j \neq 0, \text{for at least one } j = 1, \ldots,n
$$

To test this, we can use the $F$ statistic.

---

**Question.**

Rather than using the $F$ statistic, since $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are observed and are vectors, would it make any sense to test $H_0$ by checking whether $\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$ is a linearly independent set? What I mean is, checking whether the only solution to the equation

$$
\beta_1X_1 + \cdots + \beta_nX_n = 0
$$

is $\beta_1 = \cdots = \beta_n =0$.

If no, is it because we're not taking into account $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sanity check: Your proposal does not involve $Y$ in any way, which suggests it doesn't really address the root question.

More detail: For most datasets, $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ are linearly independent (and in linear regression, we actually *prefer* this to avoid [collinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) issues). And in many of those cases, some subset of them may be a good predictor of $Y$. So linear independence of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ does not really correspond to $H_0$ here.

Comment: Got it, thank you! This makes sense to me.